# How do I fix this code to get this output

Tags: sql

Code:

```
SELECT VendorID, SUM(PaymentTotal) AS PaymentSum FROM Invoices
```

Output:

```
VendorID    PaymentSum
34          1200.12
37          340.00
48          856.92
```

Comment: Your question shows clearly lack of effort of investigating more on the subject. You are new user here, don't make this attitude an habit.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT VendorID, SUM(PaymentTotal) AS PaymentSum FROM Invoices Group by VendorID
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much

Comment: Any idea how I would fix this? InvoiceID VendorID InvoiceNumber InvoiceDate InvoiceTotal PaymentTotal CreditTotal TermsID InvoiceDueDate
0 ROWS RETURNED                                                                                       I need to it show this                                                                          InvoiceID VendorID InvoiceNumber InvoiceDate InvoiceTotal PaymentTotal CreditTotal TermsID InvoiceDueDate
0 ROWS RETURNED @randy baiad